# How to return value from the Looker Golang sdk

Tags: go, looker

I'm attempting to perform the run inline query api endpoint using the Looker Golang SDK. https://github.com/looker-open-source/sdk-codegen/blob/474ee9365dafe6549826a9f627ac0a79dc0e9a56/go/sdk/v4/models.go
https://developers.looker.com/api/explorer/4.0/methods/Query/run_inline_query

However when I execute this I get a blank response back not the expected data from `fmt.Println(response)`. I also attempted to create and run, a sql query, while it looked like the API call executed I didn't receive any results in a very similar fashion. I feel like i'm missing something in getting results. I've validated these queries run in Looker.

Massive disclaimer, I'm a beginner to Golang. I'd really appreciate anyone being able to tell me what i'm doing wrong here.

```
func getDashboards(sdk *looker.LookerSDK) error {
        fields := []string{
                "dashboard.id",
                "dashboard_element.id",
                "dashboard_element.type",
                "dashboard_element.result_source",
                "query.model",
                "query.view",
                "query.formatted_fields",
                "query.id",
                "dashboard.title",
                "look.id"}
        limit := "5000"

        response, err := sdk.RunInlineQuery(
                looker.RequestRunInlineQuery{
                        ResultFormat: "json",
                        Body: looker.WriteQuery{
                                Model:  "system__activity",
                                View:   "dashboard",
                                Fields: &fields,
                                Limit:  &limit,
                        },
                }, nil)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(response)
        return err
}
```